# How to get Retinanet set up for a custom dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get Retinanet set up to train on a custom dataset but the steps are a bit unclear and I'm having trouble moving forward.

Step 1 references a file that doesn't exist, and what I guess is its replacement, `resnet.py`, has no reference to loss or optimizer as shown below. Step 2 I'm not sure where to start, is it as easy as changing the labels in the PascalVocGenerator to suit my case? Step 3 is like the first, can't find the file anywhere.

Would very much appreciate it if someone familiar with this process could point me in the right direction, am fairly new to the whole environment around ML so apologies for my ignorance.

Thanks.

https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet#csv-datasets and scroll up slightly:

> In general, the steps to train on your own datasets are:
>
> 1. Create a model by calling for instance `keras_retinanet.models.resnet50_retinanet` and compile it. Empirically, the following compile arguments have been found to work well:

```
model.compile(
    loss={
        'regression'    : keras_retinanet.losses.smooth_l1(),
        'classification': keras_retinanet.losses.focal()
    },
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.adam(lr=1e-5, clipnorm=0.001)
)
```

> 2. Create generators for training and testing data (an example is show in `keras_retinanet.preprocessing.PascalVocGenerator`).
>
>    3. Use `model.fit_generator` to start training.